# multi level groupby with function on a property

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

This is similar to [multi level groupby ramda js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406371/multi-level-groupby-ramda-js), but with a twist that is giving me trouble. In addition to a two level grouping, I'd like the inner group by to be on a processed version of the property value.

Consider data like this:

```
const data = [ 
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-a-101' },
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-b-102' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-103' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-104' } ];
```

I can pull out the key, process it and make it unique like so:

```
const getZoneFromName = n =>  join('-', slice(1, 3, split('-', n)));
uniq(map(getZoneFromName, pluck('name', data)));
```

which will get me a nice list:

```
["key-a", "key-b", "key-c"]
```

I can group the list at two levels fine:

```
const groupByTopThenZone = pipe(
  groupBy(prop("top")),
  map(groupBy(prop("name")))
);
groupByTopThenZone(data);
```

But I cannot figure out how to combine them to get the following output:

```
{
    top1: {
        "key-a": [
            {
                name: "junk-key-a-101",
                top: "top1"
            }
        ],
        "key-b": [
            {
                name: "junk-key-b-102",
                top: "top1"
            }
        ]
    },
    top2: {
        "key-c": [
            {
                name: "junk-key-c-103",
                top: "top2"
            },
            {
                name: "junk-key-c-104",
                top: "top2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm feeling a bit silly that I can't get this. Any ideas? [Here](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%20%0A%20%20%7B%20top%3A%20%27top1%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27junk-key-a-101%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20top%3A%20%27top1%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27junk-key-b-102%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20top%3A%20%27top2%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27junk-key-c-103%27%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7B%20top%3A%20%27top2%27%2C%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%27junk-key-c-104%27%20%7D%20%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20getZoneFromName%20%3D%20n%20%3D%3E%20%20join%28%27-%27%2C%20slice%281%2C%203%2C%20split%28%27-%27%2C%20n%29%29%29%3B%0A%2F%2Funiq%28map%28getZoneFromName%2C%20pluck%28%27name%27%2C%20data%29%29%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20groupByTopThenZone%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%22top%22%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28groupBy%28prop%28%22name%22%29%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%0A%2F%2A%0Aconst%20groupByTopThenZone%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20groupBy%28prop%28%22top%22%29%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28groupBy%28getZoneFromName%28prop%28%22name%22%29%29%29%29%0A%29%3B%0A%2A%2F%0AgroupByTopThenZone%28data%29%3B%0A) is a place to play with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close.  Just combining those functions with `compose`/`pipe` does the trick.

(Note here also a simplified version of `getZoneFromName`.)

```js
const {pipe, groupBy, map, prop, slice} = R

//const getZoneFromName = n =>  join('-', slice(1, 3, split('-', n)));
const getZoneFromName = slice(5, -4)

const groupByTopThenZone = pipe(
  groupBy(prop("top")),
  map(groupBy(pipe(prop("name"), getZoneFromName)))
)

const data = [{"name": "junk-key-a-101", "top": "top1"}, {"name": "junk-key-b-102", "top": "top1"}, {"name": "junk-key-c-103", "top": "top2"}, {"name": "junk-key-c-104", "top": "top2"}]

console.log(groupByTopThenZone(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Of course with this function simplified that much, it's probably easier to inline it:

```
const groupByTopThenZone = pipe(
  groupBy(prop("top")),
  map(groupBy(pipe(prop("name"), slice(5, -4)))
)
```

The main thing to remember is that `groupBy` is not necessarily tied with `prop`.  We can group on the result of *any* `String`/`Number`/`Symbol`-generating function.

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  That is a big help. The real data where the name is munged for a key is a bit more complicated and the split-slice-join is a more reliable solution, but yes, looking for simplifications helps.  I do have some confusion about the two uses of pipe.  It feels like they each work in opposite ways to me.  The inner one feels like the prop("name") feeds into the slice.  The outer "feels" like the map feeds into the groupBy(prop("top")).  I'm obviously wrong-headed on that, but it would keep me from coming up with a similar solution on my own. Can you get me on the right track?

Comment: @KevinO'Connor: They both work the way your intuition says for the inner one. The outer one first groups by `top`, yielding `{top1: [...], top2: [...]}`. Then `map` is called on that result. Note that `map(square, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}) //=> {a: 1, b: 4, c: 9}`. This works the same way, converting the arrays stored in `top1` and `top2` in your object using the function supplied to `map`, which here is the inner `groupBy(...)`. If you actually *want* something that runs in the other direction, [`compose`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#compose) is [`pipe`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipe)'s mirror twin.

Comment: Yes, I see.  Thanks again, @ScottSauyet! I hope this helps me think about this nicely in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is not using ramda, but vanilla JS.

```js
const data = [ 
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-a-101' },
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-b-102' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-103' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-104' } ];

const res = data.reduce((acc, val, ind, arr) => {
  const top = val.top;
  // if the top does not exist in the obj, create it
  if (!acc[top]) {
    acc[top] = {};
  }
  // get the key through split. you could also use a regex here
  const keyFragments = val.name.split('-');
  const key = [keyFragments[1], keyFragments[2]].join('-');
  // if the key obj prop does not exist yet, create the array
  if (!acc[top][key]) {
    acc[top][key] = []; 
  }
  // push the value
  acc[top][key].push({ name: val.name, top: val.top });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks, @quirimmo, for taking the time to answer, that is very similar to my non-ramda (I was going to say non-functional, but that wouldn't have come out right) solution.

Comment: No problem at all :) I do prefer vanilla js sometimes over these frameworks because even if they give you the job quite easy, sometimes you will loop over objects/arrays several times, when maybe you can get the job done with just one iteration

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to construct each final object and merge them all:

You can transform this object:

```
{
  "top": "top1",
  "name": "junk-key-a-101"
}
```

Into this one:

```
{
  "top1": {
    "key-a": [
      {
        "name": "junk-key-a-101",
        "top": "top1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

With these functions:

```
const key = slice(5, -4);

const obj = ({top, name}) => ({
  [top]: {
    [key(name)]: [
      {top, name}
    ]
  }
});
```

So now you can iterate on your data, transform each object and merge them together:

```
const groupByTopTenZone = reduce(useWith(mergeDeepWith(concat), [identity, obj]), {});
```

Full example:

```js
const {slice, useWith, identity, reduce, mergeDeepWith, concat} = R;

const data = [ 
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-a-101' },
  { top: 'top1',
    name: 'junk-key-b-102' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-103' },
  { top: 'top2',
    name: 'junk-key-c-104' }
];


const key = slice(5, -4);

const obj = ({top, name}) => ({
  [top]: {
    [key(name)]: [
      {top, name}
    ]
  }
});

const groupByTopTenZone = reduce(useWith(mergeDeepWith(concat), [identity, obj]), {});

console.log(
  
  groupByTopTenZone(data)

)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like the direct use of the function to create the object. I had tried something similar (without the key method you added) and then an evolve, but add trouble addressing the right item for the subsequent key-like method.  Thanks for another approach.